# Best way to create an user authentication in Objective-C iOS App

Tags: ios, json, api, authentication

I'm currently developing my own service with its own app. The service has a backend JSON API that the app uses to communicate.

Now, since an iOS app does not have sessions or cookies, I was wondering how I would go about creating a user authentication/login for my app. Should I simply locally encrypt the password/username and then, for every action (such as posting a new entry), send the user/password with the request (which seems unsafe), use a token-based system (app receives a token from the service when authenticating, saves it locally - encrypted - and then sends it with the request), or something else? Should I try to implement OAuth for my service?

I'm using the CodeIgniter Rest API for the backend.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually you can have a userToken/authToken returned on a login call first and all your subsequent api calls can have this token as one of the header param to identify thats its a authenticated session. Thats how I have done. But I am curious if someone can have a better answer.

Comment: That's what I was planning to do, but I'm also curious if there is maybe something that could be done server-wise, since I wouldn't always trust the client (I realize it's an iOS App, but security is still important).

Comment: There is an existing thread on implementation details
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841152/authenticating-users-in-iphone-app?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

My preference includes both. I normally use oauth2 with a bearer token setup (if I remember correctly). I ask for a username/email + password, encrypt the password client-side and send it to the server via Basic Auth in return for an access token which I can send on all consecutive calls. That way I can always revoke access to the backend by invalidating the access token. Oauth2 is much easier to implement than Oauth 1.0a and by following the specification, it is easy to open up your api for 3rd party apps later.

The Oauth2 access token can be send as a GET parameter, but lately I start to think sending it as a header might be preferable, to distinguish better the meta parameters like an access token and data parameters like it's or a model's actual data.