# Handling authentication in a multi-tier architecture

Tags: android, ios, authentication, web-applications

I'm writing an API, that will be used by a webapplication and native iPhone and Android apps.

The users will create accounts, login, logout etc, either through the webapplication or native apps. But all the business logic is in the API. Thus, the webapplication and the native apps are mostly thin layers containing only UI to integrate with the api.

**Question:**

What are some general ways/technologies used to authenticate users against the API, when you have this outer layer of either a webapplication or a native app.

**Related questions**

[Authenticating users in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841152/authenticating-users-in-iphone-app)

Comment: Take a look at OAuth2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out

1. OpenID
2. OAuth

and have an Identity Server set up.
Depends on what technology you are using, IdentityServer is widely available
one is [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) on a .net platform

Please do not hesitate to ask more! :D

Comment: So would you authenticate with the identityserver directly, either webapplication->identityserver and nativeapp->identityserver, which hands you back a token, and then you pass the token back to the user, which then uses this token when making requests to the webapplication, which in turn passes that to the api, where it is validated before any business logic is processed ?

Comment: Hey. The native apps would ask the api for access who asks the identity server to approve their identity with the specified token. While the web app provides user with cookies and ask the identity server for authentication. Even if its a single page app...the web server should handle the authen to keep your resources and secrets secure :) Identityserver can in the future support other nodes and modules or third parties to access your resoources and act as a single signon to your world.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>**Disclosure:** I work at Auth0.</sup>

### Tokens! Tokens! Tokens!

The most widespread approach to authenticate users in a Web API is through the use of token-based authentication. The procedure can be reduced to these steps:

1. The client application includes a token in the request (`Authorization` header).
2. The Web API validates the token and, if valid, processes the request in accordance to the information associated with the token.

This type of token is usually referred as a bearer token, because the only thing that an application has to to get access to an API protected resource is provide the token. The use of HTTPS with this type of authentication is vital in order to ensure that the token cannot be easily captured by an attacker when traveling from client to server.

The token can be classified further either as:

- by-value token - associated information is contained in the token itself
- by-reference token - associated information is kept on server-side storage that is then found using the token value as the key

A popular format used for by-value token is the JWT format ([Get Started with JSON Web Tokens](https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/)) given it's encoded in a Web friendly way and also has a fairly concise representation in order to reduce overhead on the wire.

Choosing between by-value or by-reference token is a matter of considering the pros and cons of each approach and review any specific requirements you may have. If you go with JWT, check [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) for reference on libraries supporting this format across a wide range of technologies.

### How does my application get the tokens in the first place?

Setting up your API to authenticate users with tokens can be seen as the easiest part, although the need to think about all the usual security precautions still applies.

The biggest issue with token-based authentication system, is putting in place a system that can issue tokens to your different client applications that may use different technologies or be in completely different platforms.

The answer to this, as mentioned on another answers, is to rely on [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and the [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) protocols and do one of the following:

- Implement an identity provider/authorization server system compliant with the mentioned protocols
     **⤷** *time consuming and complex, but you're following standards so you're less likely to mess up and you'll also gain interoperability*
- Delegate the authentication to a third-party authentication provider like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/)
     **⤷** *easy to get started, depending on amount of usage (the free plan on Auth0 [goes up to 7000 users](https://auth0.com/pricing)) it will cost you money instead of time*

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Fabian Bettag and @WickStargazer.

You can use [OAuth 2.0](https://www.oauth.com/) which works very well with web-app, mobile client and java-script client. Also you can use [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) to verify the identity of the End-User based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as well as to obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an inter-operable and REST-like manner.
*`OpenID Connect 1.0` is a simple identity layer on top of the `OAuth 2.0` protocol.*

**Note :-** You can also implement `SOAP` for login,registration and logout(Security sensitive APIs) to add more security to your app.

Hope this will help and let me know for any help. Happy coding!!!